# The haunting violin piece that is not on The Queen's Gambit soundtrack

Tags: soundtrack

In the music from The Queen's Gambit, does anyone know the title of the music that played in episode 7, when Beth and her companion got to the hotel room in Russia, and he said before leaving the room, "Welcome to Russia.". Beth then said, "Yes, this will do nicely." That violin quartet is so good! It's not in the soundtrack, by the way.

Answer (score 5):

I did some digging because it sounded familiar to me from when I used to play in a string quartet. It's Shostakovich's String Quartet No.3 in F Major, more specifically, the opening of the 4th movement.